# Pretty formatting result tree and line-wrapping with XSLT 2.0 result tree

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

### Background:

I have a XSLT transformation against an XML document already using:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
```

It is going through a series of XML Pipelines to get to the final result tree (stored as $finalOutput) where I need to separate results into separate XML files (1,000+) as required for this project for ingest to a web application.  Using result-document to make the separate files and copy-of to output the result tree like below:

```
<xsl:result-document href="{$filename}">    
    <xsl:copy-of select="$finalOutput" />
</xsl:result-document>
```

### Issues encountered:

**1) The first child element to a parent element is not wrapping to a new line when dynamically modified in the XML Pipelining.**

Example Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <parent>blah<child>blah</child>
        <child>blah</child>
        <child>blah<grandchild>blah</grandchild>
            <grandchild>blah</grandchild>
        </child>
        <child>blah</child>
    </parent>
</test>
```

When it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <parent>blah
        <child>blah</child>
        <child>blah</child>
        <child>blah
            <grandchild>blah</grandchild>
            <grandchild>blah</grandchild>
        </child>
        <child>blah</child>
    </parent>
</test>
```

Had already tried to insert a line-break characters on the last XML Pipeline transformation, *but it destroys the indenting of the elements.*

**2) A nice-to-have would be word wrapping with preserving indenting at 100 characters.**  Improves the readability of the documents by humans.

### Worst case alternative without XSLT:

A temp fix is opening each file manually with an XML editor that will automatically set to 100 character wrapping and auto-indent nested elements with Pretty Printing enabled.  However, don't want to have to do this to all 1,000+ files ***if I can automate into the XML Pipeline.***

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#xml-indent says "Whitespace characters MUST NOT be added adjacent to a text node that contains non-whitespace characters." so not indenting e.g. `<parent>blah<child>` is correct. Which XSLT processor do you use, have you checked whether it allows some custom serialization according to your needs?

Comment: That makes sense then on the whitespace indenting.  Using Saxton PE 6.x in a trial version of OxygenXML editor.  Will check when back home.  Wonder if Tidy has something...